# R: Group and sum by rows for specific subsets

Tags: r

I can't manage to solve the following problem and need therefore your help:

## Starting point:

```
x1<-matrix(c("A","A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B","B",
"x1","x2","x3","x4","x5","x1","x2","x3","x4","x5",
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10),nrow = 10, ncol = 3)
x1
```

## Desired result:

```
x2<- matrix(c("A","A","B","B",6,9,21,19),nrow = 4, ncol = 2)
x2
```

- For A: x1+x1+x3 = 1+2+3 = 6, x4+x5 = 4+5 = 9
- For B: x1+x2+x3 = 6+7+8 = 21, x4+x5 = 9+10 = 19

I would like to avoid generating two separate datasets (one for x1,x2,x3 and the other for x4,x5). Has anybody an idea how to solve this problem?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: #The two answers were very helpful 
dfa <- data.frame(item=c("X","X","X","X","Y","Y","Y","Y"), 
                 category=c("A","B","C","A","C","B","A","C"),
                 number=c(8,3,5,1,3,6,7,5)) 
dfb<-dfa %>% filter(!grepl("B|C",category)) 
dfb<-aggregate(cbind(number)~item+category,dfb,sum) 
dfc<-dfa %>% filter(grepl("B|C",category)) 
dfc$category[dfc$category<-"E"] 
dfc<-aggregate(cbind(number)~item+category,dfc,sum) 
rbind(dfb,dfc)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`data.table`

```
library(data.table)
as.data.table(x1)[, .(vsum = sum(as.numeric(V3))), .(V1, grepl('[1-3]', V2))]
#    V1 grepl vsum
# 1:  A  TRUE    6
# 2:  A FALSE    9
# 3:  B  TRUE   21
# 4:  B FALSE   19
```

Base R:

```
aggregate(as.numeric(x1[,3]), by = list(!grepl('[1-3]', x1[, 2]), x1[, 1]), sum)[, -1]
#   Group.2  x
# 1       A  6
# 2       A  9
# 3       B 21
# 4       B 19
```

Comment: Thanks a lot - a very helpful approach!

Comment: And: Effective and impressive solution.

Answer (score 2):

How about this. We make a new variable, group by the two variables of interest, then summarise.

```
library(dplyr)

x1<-matrix(c("A","A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B","B",
"x1","x2","x3","x4","x5","x1","x2","x3","x4","x5",
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10),nrow = 10, ncol = 3)

x1 %>% 
  as.data.frame() %>%
  mutate(sub_group = case_when(grepl("[1-3]", V2) ~ 1, TRUE ~ 2),
         V3 = as.numeric(as.character(V3))) %>%
  group_by(V1, sub_group) %>%
  summarise(total = sum(V3)) %>%
  select(-sub_group) 
#> # A tibble: 4 x 2
#> # Groups:   V1 [2]
#>   V1    total
#>   <fct> <dbl>
#> 1 A         6
#> 2 A         9
#> 3 B        21
#> 4 B        19
```

Created on 2018-09-19 by the [reprex
package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Comment: not that it really matters because you need to convert `V3` to numeric, but you can always create a helper column in the `group_by` statement as well. E.g., `group_by(V1, sub_group = case_when(grepl("[1-3]", V2) ~ 1, TRUE ~ 2)`